# ASP.NET RC1 Update 1 in Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have my startup developed in ASP.NET Core RC1 and published in Azure like a web site.

Sometimes I don't know why, the web app is down. I don't know what exactly happens, but I have an error in GCI like this:

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process.

I have about 100K users, but it happens in hours that I don't have a lot of users using the web.

Here you have some screenshot about the errors:

[image]

I have created an API in a version of ASP.NET 4.5 to upload images to the platform (I know about the error of uploading files in Kestrel) and I'm in a point where I don't know what happens.

I'm using Application Insight in my platform, and I have received an alert, about the service:

> 90% of all the failed requests had this exception: Exception
>   method:   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   Exception type:   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvException

I am totally frustrated about how to solve the error. My web app was totally fine when I was working in ASP.NET 4.5 in AWS, but now, I have a lot of problems...

What can I do? Any idea or help? Thanks.

Comment: I also encountered the same error that you are confronting and I too was very frustrated but I came to know that my other Azure Services that I was using with my Web App, was not configured correctly while I'm in production. Make sure that your application settings properties are named correctly while (If you are using any) and double check the connection string. That's how I resolved the problem.

Comment: Any tutorial or help to check all information? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any helpful tutorial. This can be solved by watching your code and workflow of your application. Make sure that again your other Azure Services and other Azure App Settings are names and configure appropriately in production site.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested with no results...

Comment: Within the configuration tab of Azure Web Sites there is a setting for "Always On" - is yours set to 'true'?? If not, the site may be shutting down due to inactivity.

Comment: Yes, always on is enabled... Thanks!!